# Is there a work around for CocoaPods mutually exclusive frameworks vs static libraries in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

CocoaPods requires that either all dependencies are frameworks or all dependencies are static libraries. It is not supported if you mix these two within the same workspace.

Is there any work around when you find yourself wanting to depend on Pods of both types?

I understand that I could just bring the code into my project, but this is pretty annoying, given numerous transitive dependencies and projects that are so reliant on CocoaPods that they do not have .xcodeproj files to drop in.

Is it possible to create a framework project that uses static CocoaPods libraries and expose that as a private pod?

Are there any other work-arounds?

Comment: I should note that the main project as well as most of the Pods are Swift. The static libraries in question are Objective-C.

Comment: Can you clarify why do you need to do this? Maybe there is simpler way to accomplish desired result. (You can compile objc Pods to framework too..)